# How to find the kafka version in linux

Tags: apache-kafka

How to find the kafka version in linux?
whether there is a way to find the installed kafka version other than mentioning the version while downloading it?

Comment: possible with command [kafka-topics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51782038/1592191)

Answer (score 133):

Not sure if there's a convenient way, but you can just inspect your `kafka/libs` folder. You should see files like `kafka_2.10-0.8.2-beta.jar`, where `2.10` is Scala version and `0.8.2-beta` is Kafka version.

Answer (score 130):

> ## Kafka 2.0 have the fix([KIP-278](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-278+-+Add+version+option+to+Kafka%27s+commands)) for it:
>
> ```
> kafka-topics.sh --version
> ```

Or

> ```
> kafka-topics --version
> ```

---

## Using confluent utility:

Kafka version check can be done with `confluent` utility which comes by default with Confluent platform(*`confluent` utility can be added to cluster separately as well - credits [cricket_007](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308683/cricket-007)*).

```
${confluent.home}/bin/confluent version kafka
```

Checking the version of other Confluent platform components like *ksql schema-registry* and *connect*

```
[confluent-4.1.0]$ ./bin/confluent version kafka
1.1.0-cp1

[confluent-4.1.0]$ ./bin/confluent version connect
4.1.0

[confluent-4.1.0]$ ./bin/confluent version schema-registry
4.1.0

[confluent-4.1.0]$ ./bin/confluent version ksql-server
4.1.0
```

Comment: That is still wrong, sorry (and it works for Kafka 2.0+ as well (confluent 5.x +). You have a **remotely running** Kafka cluster with **any version**, then `confluent version` does you no good.

Comment: When I use Confluent utility as you mentioned, I'm getting this error. Error: unknown command "kafka" for "confluent version"

Comment: what is the `confluent version`?

Comment: This gives the version of the "kafka-topics.sh" so you can not identify the version of Kafka actually running this way :-(

Answer (score 53):

There is nothing like `kafka --version` at this point. So you should either check the version from your `kafka/libs/` folder or you can run

```
find ./libs/ -name \*kafka_\* | head -1 | grep -o '\kafka[^\n]*'
```

from your kafka folder (and it will do the same for you). It will return you something like `kafka_2.9.2-0.8.1.1.jar.asc` where `0.8.1.1` is your kafka version.

Comment: dumb question: where is one's "kafka folder" typically located?

Comment: obvious answer: `/usr/local/kafka`

Comment: realistic answer: depends on your platform and how you installed it

Comment: If installed via yum on centos then - `find /usr/share/java/kafka -name \*kafka_\* | head -1 | grep -o '\kafka[^\n]*'`

Comment: `find / -name \*kafka_\* | head -1 | grep -o '\kafka[^\n]*'`

Answer (score 38):

There are several methods to find kafka version

> **Method 1 simple:-**

```
ps -ef|grep kafka
```

it will displays all running kafka clients in the console...
Ex:- /usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/bin/../libs/kafka-clients-**0.10.0.2.5.3.0-37**.jar
we are using 0.10.0.2.5.3.0-37 version of kafka

> **Method 2:-**
>   go to

```
cd /usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/libs
ll |grep kafka
```

**Ex:-** kafka_2.10-**0.10.0.2.5.3.0-37**.jar
kafka-clients-**0.10.0.2.5.3.0-37**.jar

same result as method 1 we can find the version of kafka using in kafka libs.

Answer (score 28):

You can grep the logs to see the version. Let's say kafka is installed under `/usr/local/kafka`, then:

```
$ grep "Kafka version" /usr/local/kafka/logs/*

/usr/local/kafka/logs/kafkaServer.out: INFO Kafka version : 0.9.0.1 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
```

will reveal the version

Comment: If using Docker: `docker logs kafka | egrep -i "kafka\W+version"`

Answer (score 12):

If you want to check the version of a specific Kafka broker, run this CLI on the broker*

```sh
kafka-broker-api-versions.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --version
```

where `localhost:9092` is the accessible `<hostname|IP Address>:<port>` this API will check (`localhost` can be used if it's the same host you're running this command on). Example of output:

```sh
2.4.0 (Commit:77a89fcf8d7fa018)
```

---

* Apache Kafka comes with a variety of console tools in the `./bin` sub-directory of your Kafka download; e.g. `~/kafka/bin/`

Comment: This seems to give the version of the "kafka-broker-api-versions.sh" so you can not identify the version of Kafka actually running this way :-(  (Or at least when I run the same command with different versions of Kafka against the same running instance on localhost I gett different versions returned.

Comment: Useful link: [KAFKA-4457. Add BrokerVersionCommand PR#2184](https://github.com/apache/kafka/pull/2184)

Comment: Related link: [Retrieving Supported API versions](https://kafka.apache.org/protocol#api_versions)

Comment: @SamuelÅslund, _This seems to give the version of the "kafka-broker-api-versions.sh"_ that doesn't make sense to me. Why would one write a command to output its own version? Its purpose should be providing the broker version.

Comment: Also it's not clear to me what you meant by _run the same command with different versions of Kafka against the same running instance_; I provided the link of the `kafka-broker-api-versions.sh` PR (Pull Request), so you can find its meaning, since it seem to lack proper documentation. I hope that helps you somehow.

Comment: The most intuitive of all the answers, let's vote to push this answer up!

Answer (score 7):

Simple way on *macOS* e.g. installed via [homebrew](http://brewformulas.org/kafka)

```
$ ls -l $(which kafka-topics)
/usr/local/bin/kafka-topics -> ../Cellar/kafka/0.11.0.1/bin/kafka-topics
```

Answer (score 6):

`cd kafka`

`./bin/kafka-topics.sh --version`

Answer (score 5):

You can use for Debian/Ubuntu:

```
dpkg -l|grep kafka
```

Expected result should to be like:

```
ii  confluent-kafka-2.11                   0.11.0.1-1                                 all          publish-subscribe messaging rethought as a distributed commit log
ii  confluent-kafka-connect-elasticsearch  3.3.1-1                                    all          Kafka Connect connector for copying data between Kafka and Elasticsearch
ii  confluent-kafka-connect-hdfs           3.3.1-1                                    all          Kafka Connect connector for copying data between Kafka and Hadoop HDFS
ii  confluent-kafka-connect-jdbc           3.3.1-1                                    all          Kafka Connect connector for JDBC-compatible databases
ii  confluent-kafka-connect-replicator     3.3.1-1                                    all          Kafka Connect connector for replicating topics between Kafka clusters
ii  confluent-kafka-connect-s3             3.3.1-1                                    all          Kafka Connect S3 connector for copying data between Kafka and
ii  confluent-kafka-connect-storage-common 3.3.1-1                                    all          Kafka Connect Storage Common contains packages used by storage
ii  confluent-kafka-rest                   3.3.1-1                                    all          A REST proxy for Kafka
```

Answer (score 5):

I found an easy way to do this without searching directories or log files:

```
kafka-dump-log --version
```

Output looks like this:

> 5.3.0-ccs (Commit:6481debc2be778ee)

Comment: this is the confluent version, not kafka version

Answer (score 4):

go to kafka/libs folder
we can see multiple jars search for something similar  kafka_2.11-0.10.1.1.jar.asc  in this case the kafka version is 0.10.1.1

Answer (score 2):

Change directories to the Kafka home directory.

Use command-line utilities to enter the following command:

```
$  bin/kafka-topics.sh --version
```

It will return the version running:

```
$  bin/kafka-topics.sh --version
3.3.1 (Commit:e23c59d00e687ff5)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you install Kafka in Centos7 with confluent :

```
yum install confluent-platform-oss-2.11
```

You can see the version of Kafka with :

```
yum deplist confluent-platform-oss-2.11
```

You can read : confluent-kafka-2.11 >= **0.10.2.1**

Answer (score 0):

To find the Kafka Version, We can use the `jps` command which show all the java processes running on the machine.

Step 1: Let's say, you are running Kafka as the root user, so login to your machine with root and use `jps -m`. It will show the result like

```
4979 Jps -m
9434 Kafka config/server.properties
```

Step 2: From the above result, you can take the PID for Kafka application and use `pwdx  9434` which reports the current directory of the process. the result will be like

```
9434: /apps/kafka_2.12-2.4.0
```

here you can see the Kafka version which is 2.12-2.4.0

Answer (score 0):

```
cd confluent-7.2.0/share/java/kafka
```

then

```
$ ls -lha | grep kafka
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 5.3M Jul  5 09:45 kafka_2.13-7.2.0-ccs.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 4.8M Jul  5 09:45 kafka-clients-7.2.0-ccs.jar
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   26 Jul 23 10:10 kafka.jar -> ./kafka_2.13-7.2.0-ccs.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 9.4K Jul  5 09:45 kafka-log4j-appender-7.2.0-ccs.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 458K Jul  5 09:45 kafka-metadata-7.2.0-ccs.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 182K Jul  5 09:45 kafka-raft-7.2.0-ccs.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  36K Jul  5 09:45 kafka-server-common-7.2.0-ccs.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  84K Jul  5 09:45 kafka-shell-7.2.0-ccs.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 151K Jul  5 09:45 kafka-storage-7.2.0-ccs.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  23K Jul  5 09:45 kafka-storage-api-7.2.0-ccs.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1.6M Jul  5 09:45 kafka-streams-7.2.0-ccs.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  41K Jul  5 09:45 kafka-streams-examples-7.2.0-ccs.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 161K Jul  5 09:45 kafka-streams-scala_2.13-7.2.0-ccs.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  52K Jul  5 09:45 kafka-streams-test-utils-7.2.0-ccs.jar
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 127K Jul  5 09:45 kafka-tools-7.2.0-ccs.jar
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also type

```
cat /build.info
```

This will give you an output like this

```
BUILD_BRANCH=master
BUILD_COMMIT=434160726dacc4a1a592fe6036891d6e646a3a4a
BUILD_TIME=2017-05-12T16:02:04Z
DOCKER_REPO=index.docker.io/landoop/fast-data-dev
KAFKA_VERSION=0.10.2.1
CP_VERSION=3.2.1
```

Comment: Your answer does not mention where this build.info file is located.

Comment: This appears to be very specific to the Landoop fast-data Docker image @Newbee `/build.info` is at the root of the container

Answer (score -1):

To check kafka version :

```
cd /usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/libs
ls kafka_*.jar
```