# Kafka version on hortonworks command line or steps

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, apache-storm, hortonworks-data-platform

I need to know which kafka version i'm using on my sandbox.

My kafka Spout doesn't consume anything from kafka brokers even if the data is stored in brokers cause is the default consumer consumes data but my kafka spout doesn't.

[image: STORM UI]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the kafka version in linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27606065/how-to-find-the-kafka-version-in-linux)

Comment: Please refer to the [chart on this page](http://hortonworks.com/products/hdp/)  for your particular version of HDP.